# Java Serial Port communication API

Tags: java, serial-port, port, rxtx

As a Java serial port communication API, currently I am using [RXTX](http://rxtx.qbang.org/wiki/index.php/Main_Page) API. But with that API, it seems have some issues (with serial port communication) such as get delay to bind with COM port, lots some characters on device output received etc. Is there any better API for this?

With many articles I have seen Java haven't good support for Serial port communication. In that case for better performance, whether I can implement this serial port communication with C++ or C# and integrate with my Java application? Thanks.

Comment: I am sure you solved this topic. Which library would you recommend today?

Comment: @Brethlosze Sorry I have used the RXTX and at that time I didn't have enough time to research for finding the best one.

Answer (score 2):

You can take a look at https://blogs.oracle.com/jtc/entry/java_serial_communications_revisited
where they analize the status of java serial communication.

They talk about jSSC
https://code.google.com/p/java-simple-serial-connector/
and Device I/O Project http://openjdk.java.net/projects/dio/ , and also RXTX

Answer (score 2):

If you are using Windows, you can take a look at https://github.com/thibautd/JSerial. Please note that I'm the author of the library, but I created it because no one fit my needs (for example it's hard to re-compile the native part of jSSC).

JSerial is MIT-licensed (you can use it in closed-source applications) and delivered with a full Visual Studio project if you need to modify the native part.

Hope it may be useful :-)

Answer (score 1):

I had a pretty nice experience with [JSerialComm](http://fazecast.github.io/jSerialComm/) library. I've used this library on Linux and Windows 7 operating systems successfully. But I am not sure about windows 10. Also developers say that it works on OS X and Android. Besides said above, with this library you don't need to install any native library, it already there.